# Force redraw of UIView after scaling with animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

In a custom UIView I have overridden drawRect and draw several lines.

Then the UIView is scaled with animation:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
      delay: 0.1
      animations: ^{
           myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoom, zoom);}
      completion:^(BOOL finished) { }
 ];
```

The drawn lines obviously change their thickness (width).

How can I force a redraw of the lines to obtain original width? I think that I have to put somewhere the line

```
 [myView setNeedsDisplay]
```

But I tried different positions to no avail. Or there is another solution?

Comment: Did you put the line inside the completion block?

Comment: yes, but it does not work.

Comment: Instead of using a transform you should simply animate a change in frame. As long as your `drawRect:` properly draws the view regardless of its size, you should get the desired effect.

Comment: You mean this?CGRect bounds = myView.bounds;
     bounds.size.width *= zoom;
     bounds.size.height *= zoom;
     myView.bounds = bounds;

Comment: Something like that. Of course you should set the bounds inside the animations block.